# How to set the LANG for a python script running through systemd?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, systemd, systemctl

On the server where I run the program the default encoding is `latin-1`, and when I try to run a python script I get an error like `'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position`, etc.

I know you can change the default locale with `dpkg-reconfigure locales`, but for me the other way is more convenient:

```
LANG=en_US.utf8 python3.11 main.py
```

Now the question remains: is there any way to put the `LANG` when I run the script using the `systemctl`?

I use this `script.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=My Script
After=syslog.target
 
[Service]
Type=simple
User=username
Group=sudo
WorkingDirectory=/home/username/project_dir/
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3.11 main.py
 
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to simply override the LANG variable, you can add an `Environment` line to the service definition e.g.

```
[Unit]
Description=My Script
After=syslog.target
 
[Service]
Type=simple
User=username
Group=sudo
WorkingDirectory=/home/username/project_dir/
Environment="LANG=en_US.utf8"
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3.11 main.py
 
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

You can also replace `ExecStart` with an invocation of env…

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/env LANG=en_US.utf8 /usr/bin/python3.11 main.py
```